# count the number of occurrences for each date in the calendar table and for each employee

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display for each employee the number of lines per date. including dates with 0 lines.
I have an employee table, a calendar table with the working days and another table called tasks.
I succeeded in counting the lines of the submitted dates but I cannot display 0 for the dates which appear in the calendar table but not in the tasks table for each employe.

```
select e.matricule
     , coalesce(subq.counter, 0)
     , subq.dt
from employe e
left join 
     (select c.dt
            , count(t.date) as counter
            , t.matricule
      from calendar c
      left join tasks t 
        on t.date = c.dt
      group by c.dt
          , t.matricule
     )as SUBQ
   on SUBQ.matricule = E.matricule
```

```
table employe(id, matricule, name) 
       
       1,101, name1 
       2,202, name2 
       3, 303, name3 

       table calendar(id, dt) 

       1, 2020-01-01
       2, 2020-01-02 
       3, 2020-01-03 

       table tasks(id, task, matricule, date)

       1, task1, 101, 2020-01-03 
       2, task3, 101, 2020-01-03 
       3, task2, 202, 2020-01-01 

       Result matricule, date, counter
       101, 2020-01-01, 0 
       101, 2020-01-02, 0 
       101, 2020-01-03, 2 
       202, 2020-01-01, 1 
       202, 2020-01-02, 0 
       202, 2020-01-03, 0 
       303, 2020-01-01, 0 
       303, 2020-01-02, 0 
       303, 2020-01-03, 0
```

Comment: For future reference: think about adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) to your question. It can significantly increase the likelihood of receiving an answer, as well as speed up the process.

Comment: sum dos'nt resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using sum for not null value = 1 in left join

```
select e.matricule
     , coalesce(subq.counter, 0)
     , subq.dt
from employe e
left join 
     (select c.dt
            , sum(case when t.date is null then 0 else 1 end ) as counter
            , t.matricule
      from calendar c
      left join tasks t on t.date = c.dt
      group by c.dt, t.matricule
     )as SUBQ
   on SUBQ.matricule = E.matricule
```

but looking to your sample seems  you need cross join between employee and calendar

```
   select tt.matricula, tt.dt , sum(case when t.date is null then 0 else 1 end ) as counter
   from (
       select e.matricula, c.dt 
       from employe e
       cross join calendar c
   ) tt
   left join  tasks t ON tt.matricule = t.matricule and tt.dt = t.date
   group by tt.matricula, tt.dt
```

Comment: I give you an example of what I want to display
table employe(id, matricule, name)
1,101, name1
2,202, name2
3, 303, name3
table calendar(id, dt)
1, 2020-01-01
2, 2020-01-02
3, 2020-01-03
table tasks(id, task, matricule, date)

1, task1, 101, 2020-01-03
2, task3, 101, 2020-01-03
3, task2, 202, 2020-01-01
Result
matricule, date, counter
101, 2020-01-01, 0   
101, 2020-01-02, 0  
101, 2020-01-03, 2
202, 2020-01-01, 1
202, 2020-01-02, 0
202, 2020-01-03, 0
303, 2020-01-01, 0   
303, 2020-01-02, 0  
303, 2020-01-03, 0

Comment: @Betty  instead of add  the sample in comment .. update your question and add the sample directly in question ..and add  also the expcted result

Comment: anyway answer  updated  with a suggestion